# ASP .NET 5 templates missing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-templates, asp.net5

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 community edition. But, suddenly all my ASP .Net 5 templates are missing. Any help would be highly appreciated

[image]

Comment: Did you install update 2?

Comment: Yes. There are no pending updates in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new version of ASP.NET 5 was released a few weeks ago.  It's now called ASP.NET Core and currently is at version RC2.  So it doesn't use the ASP.NET 5 templates anymore. Under the Web templates you should have three selections:

**ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)** - Used to create classic web applications.

**ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)** - Used to create pre-release ASP.NET Core applications that are cross-platform compatible.

**ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)** - Used to create pre-release ASP.NET Core applications that are dependent on .NET Framework.

I installed Visual Studio Update 2 and ASP.NET Core RC2 one after the other.  So I'm not sure which one changed the Web templates.  But it seems that Update 2 did it since your ASP.NET 5 templates are gone and I assume you haven't installed ASP.NET Core RC2.

I would suggest upgrading to ASP.NET Core RC2 by following the install guide [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows).  The ASP.NET 5 templates are gone for good.  And there have been big changes with the latest release.  Read about these changes [here](http://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/dnx-migration.html) and [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rc2.html).

Comment: So you mean I can not get ASP.NET 5 templates back?

Comment: That's correct.  There have been big changes with the latest release and the ASP.NET 5 templates are not compatible with the latest release.

Comment: That's unfortunate!! I've been developing an web application using ASP.NET 5.. Now I'm afraid that I cannot continue to use same features.

Comment: You can migrate your project.  The same features still exist but many of them will be in new namespaces.  The code will still work after you update your project dependencies (NuGet packages) and your references.  My advice is to create a new project in RC2 and copy your code to the new project and then figure what dependencies you need.  If you want to migrate your project though, [here is a guid](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rc2.html).  It's worth a read either way because it outlines some of the biggest changes in RC2.